# Fail to pass result in request-promise

Tags: node.js, promise, request-promise

I would like to call an API that helped to extract some data from Facebook. I expect the API will keep looping itself on or before a specified date. If an expected result is found, then it should return a json. But the code below, it always returns an empty json.

```
   app.get('/fb/test', (req, res) => {
      const options = {
         method: 'GET',
         uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/tagged_places',
         qs: {
            access_token: token,
            limit: 10,
            fields: 'created_time,id,place'
         }
      };
      request(options)
      .then(fbRes => {
        var found = false;
        loop(fbRes);

    function loop(returnData){
      const parsedRes = JSON.parse(returnData).data;
      var start = moment.tz("2010-06-01 00:00", timezone).format();

      for (var i = 0; i < parsedRes.length; i++) {

         var date = moment.tz(parsedRes[i].created_time, timezone).format();

         if( date >= start ){
             console.log(parsedRes[i].place.name);

             if(parsedRes[i].place.name == "Moscow, Russia"){
                 found = true;
                 res.json({ result: true });
                 break;
             }else if(i==parsedRes.length-1 && found == false){
                let newOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    uri: JSON.parse(returnData).paging.next
                };

                request(newOptions)
                .then(newData => { 
                    loop(newData);
                  })
                .catch(function (err) {});

                return ture;
             }else{
               //break;
             }

         }else{
            res.json({ result: false });
         }
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
     res.json(err);
   });

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve paginated data recursively using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139145/retrieve-paginated-data-recursively-using-promises)

Comment: Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549164/how-can-i-do-pagination-with-bluebird-promises.